# Looking for a quicker way of fuzzy string matching

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

I am using fuzzywuzzy in python for fuzzy string matching. I have a set of names in a list named HKCP_list which I am matching against a pandas column iteratively to get the best possible match. Given below is the code for it

```
import fuzzywuzzy
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz,process

def search_func(row):
    chk = process.extract(row,HKCP_list,scorer=fuzz_token_sort_ratio)[0]
    return chk

wc_df['match']=wc_df['concat_name'].map(search_func)
```

The wc_df dataframe contains the column 'concat_name' which needs to be matched with every name in the list HKCP_list. The above code took around 2 hours to run with 6K names in the list and 11K names in the column 'concat_name'.

I have to rerun this on another data set where are 89K names in the list and 120K names in the column. In order to speed up the process, I got an idea in the following question on Stackoverflow

[Vectorizing or Speeding up Fuzzywuzzy String Matching on PANDAS Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52631291/vectorizing-or-speeding-up-fuzzywuzzy-string-matching-on-pandas-column)

In one of the comments in the answer in the above, it has been advised to compare names that have the same 1st letter. The 'concat_name' column that I am comparing with is a derived column obtained by concatenating 'first_name' and 'last_name' columns in the dataframe. Hence I am using the following function to match the 1st letter (since this is a token sort score that I am considering, I am comparing the 1st letter of both the first_name and last_name with the elements in the list). Given below is the code:

```
wc_df['first_name_1stletter'] = wc_df['first_name'].str[0]
wc_df['last_name_1stletter'] = wc_df['last_name'].str[0]

import time
start_time=time.time()
def match_func(row):
    CP_subset=[x for x in HKCP_list if x[0]==row['first_name_1stletter'] or x[0]==row['last_name_1stletter']]
    return CP_subset
wc_df['list_to_match']=wc_df.apply(match_func,axis=1)
end_time=time.time()
print(end_time-start_time)
```

The above step took 1600 second with 6K X 11K data. The 'list_to_match' column contains the list of names to be compared for each concat_name. Now here I have to again take the list_to_match element and pass individual elements in a list and do the fuzzy string matching using the process.extract method. Is there a more elegant and faster way of doing this in the same step as above?

PS: Editing this to add an example as to how the list and the dataframe column looks like.

```
HKCp_list=['jeff bezs','michael blomberg','bill gtes','tim coook','elon musk'] 
concat_name=['jeff bezos','michael bloomberg','bill gates','tim cook','elon musk','donald trump','kim jong un', 'narendra modi','michael phelps']
first_name=['jeff','michael','bill','tim','elon','donald','kim','narendra','michael']
last_name=['bezos','bloomberg','gates','cook','musk','trump','jong un', 'modi','phelps']
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'first_name':first_name,'last_name':last_name,'concat_name':concat_name})
```

Each row of the 'concat_name' in df has to be compared against the elements of HKcp_list.

PS: editing today to reflect the ":" and the row in the 2nd snippet of code I missed yesterday

Regards,
Nirvik

Comment: Not sure how it holds in terms of speed, but I wrote a function for this problem which you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56315491/9081267)

Comment: Btw, if you add some example data, we can test and reproduce an answer for you.

Comment: Hi Erfan, thanks a lot for your response. I have added an example of how the list and the dataframe looks like

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56315491/9081267) I wrote in another answer, not 100% sure how it holds in terms of speed, you can try for yourself:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

# Make dataframe out of list
HKCp = pd.DataFrame({'names':HKCp_list})

# Use fuzzy_merge function
fuzzy_merge(df, HKCp, 'concat_name', 'names')
```

**Output**

```
  first_name  last_name        concat_name           matches
0       jeff      bezos         jeff bezos         jeff bezs
1    michael  bloomberg  michael bloomberg  michael blomberg
2       bill      gates         bill gates         bill gtes
3        tim       cook           tim cook         tim coook
4       elon       musk          elon musk         elon musk
5     donald      trump       donald trump                  
6        kim    jong un        kim jong un                  
7   narendra       modi      narendra modi                  
8    michael     phelps     michael phelps
```

**Note** you can play with the `treshold` argument to get *less exact matches*

Comment: Hi Erfan, thanks a lot for your response. I looked up the function. It essentially does the same thing as I had shared in the 1st snippet of code. I have figured out a way to make the list of names dynamic for each instance of comparison in the data frame. Adding the code as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Given below is the code that I have used to make the comparison of list dynamic for each instance:

```
import fuzzywuzzy
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz,process

wc_df['first_name_1stletter'] = wc_df['first_name'].str[0]
wc_df['last_name_1stletter'] = wc_df['last_name'].str[0]

import time
start_time=time.time()
def match_func(row):

    CP_subset=[x for x in HKCP_list if x[0]==row['first_name_1stletter'] or x[0]==row['last_name_1stletter']]
    if len(CP_subset)>0:
        chk=process.extract(row['concat_name'],CP_subset,scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio)[0]
    else:
        chk = "No item to match"

    return chk

wc_df['match']=wc_df.apply(match_func,axis=1)

end_time=time.time()
print(end_time-start_time)
```

The above code for 6K X 11K comparisons took around 2600 seconds instead of the 7000 seconds as per the 1st snippet of the code posted in the question.